# ajax get key values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

Trying to do a GET on the values entered for some text fields but when console logging data ( i thought defined in the ajax) it just returns my whole page html.

```
<script>
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
        var firstName = $("#firstName").val();
        var LastName = $("#LastName").val();
        var Phone = $("#Phone").val();
        var Party = $("#Party").val();
        var dateof = $("#dateof").val();
        var Timeof = $("#Timeof").val();

    submit.onclick = function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "reserve.html",
            data: firstName, LastName, Phone, Party, dateof, Timeof,
            cache: true,
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });}})
;



    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

I am also a bit lost as how to post the results to say a console.log (not setting up a server yet...) would I use ajax type post? how does this differ from get?

THANKS!

Comment: $.ajax makes a HTTP request to the server. The success callback is called after the server round trip has been completed successfully. You need understand this. Refer to the jquery doc http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: If you're making a request for an html page...you're gonna get an html page

Comment: if I change the URL destination to a blank .php page i created will this solve it? and why are some of my data types highlighted and other are not?